# remove one comma using a python script

Tags: python, csv, vim

I have csv file with a line that looks something like this:

```
,,,,,,,,,,
```

That's 10 commas. I wish to remove only the last (i.e. the 10th) comma, so that the line changes to:

```
,,,,,,,,,
```

Has anyone had any experience dealing with a case like this? I use the vim text editor also. So, any help using python script or text editing commands using vim would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you always removing just commas or are you trying to remove the last field in your CSV?

Comment: Try to describe a little more concisely when you would like the comma removed, ie is there a number of commas you are looking for, just 1 less comma, etc.

Comment: I am trying to remove just the last comma as described in my question. The number need not be the 10th, it was only an example. Yes, I am looking for one less comma

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing last comma in current line in vim:
`:s/,$//`

The same for lines n through m:
`:n,ms/,$//`

The same for whole file:
`:%s/,$//`

Comment: +1 for just regex. This assumes that the comma is always the last character in the line (no whitespace), which should be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it in the simplest case, once you've updated your question with what you're looking for, I'll update the code.

```
commas = ",,,,,,,,,,,"
print commas.replace(","*10, ","*9)
```

If you want to remove the last comma on any given line you can do:

```
import re
commas = """,,,,,,,,,,
            ,,,,,,,,,,"""
print re.sub(r',$', '', commas, re.MULTILINE)
```

And if, in any file, you want to take a line that is just 10 commas and make it 9 commas:

```
import re
commas = ",,,,,,,,,,\n,,,,,,,,,,\n,,,,,,,,,,"
print re.sub(r'^,{10}$', ','*9, commas, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: You could improve code readability by using ',' * n to generate string having n commas. Like ',' * 10.

Comment: Yeah, counting commas was annoying but I was under the impression that you needed to join the strings after you did that kind of operation (I have to juggle .Net and python all the time). Amended with your improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
sed -i 's/,$//' file.csv
```

Comment: Actually, you could use the same as in vim here, so `sed -i 's/,$//' file.csv` to easily refer to only one last comma.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, I didn't want to alter a line with nine commas.

Answer (score 1):

I really love the VIM normal command. So if you want to remove the last "column" from this CSV file I'd do like this:

```
:%normal $F,D
```

In other words, execute in every line of this file (`%`) the following procedures (`normal`):

1. `$` - go to the end of the line;
2. `F,` - Move the cursor to the previews comma in this line;
3. `D` - Delete from the cursor until the end of the line;

Also, this can be used with ranges (from line 1 to 20):

```
:1,20normal $F,D
```

But if there are nothing but a lot of commas with no data between them, you can simply do:

```
:%normal $X
```